# iOS 7 3.5" vs 4" shifting content off screen

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I'm preparing an App for launch and going through testing for iOS 7, using iPhone 4 (3.5" screen) and iPhone 5 (4" screen) in XCode 5.  Trouble I'm having is the content for iPhone 4, in particular the bottom bar (with bar items) is not visible.

The only way I can get it visible is before I run, go to Storyboard, and change the size from "Inferred" to retina 3.5".  Would my solution be create two storyboards, one for 3.5" and one for 4"?

Else would it make more sense to programmatically detect the devise and shift content up or down?

```
 CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
if (screenSize.height > 480.0f) {
    /*Do iPhone 5 stuff here.*/
} else {
    /*Do iPhone 4 stuff here.*/
}
 } else {
/*Do iPad stuff here.*/
 }
```

Comment: Both ways are ok, however Apple likes you to use AutoLayout. If you aren't, you can try setting the auto resizing masks properly and it should work too

Comment: I am using AutoLayout, and would rather use the Storyboard if possible.  That is why I'm confused on why this adjustment isn't happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could theoretically go that route, however, the better route is to use autolayout in your storyboard. Go into your storyboard, and check the "Use Autolayout" checkbox in the file inspector. Then select the layout in the storyboard, and go to `Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Reset to suggested constraints for _____`

Note that you may have to do some tweaking to the constraints that they give you to be sure that everything appears where you want it. For that, [Apple's documentation on Auto Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) will help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue than you, and my problem was the constrains of my view.
  Maybe you should check your Constrains. One suggestion is: go to Editor > Resolve Auto Layouts Issues > Reset to suggested constrains. But you are not so familiarized with settings of constrains, i suggest this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3to5m3zuTEw
  It's very objective and easy to understand.